# Windows Forms: DataGridView Binding Question

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a **Winform DataGridView**, which has a number of predefined columns. Now I have an **array of objects** (the object structure conforms to the defined gridview columns) and I want to bind the gridview to this array (with gridview.datasource = array)

The problem is now, that I get several new columns in the grid after the predefined columns (the predefinded columns remain empty). How can I achive, that the array data is loaded into the predefined columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DataPropertyName`s of the existing columns to match the properties of the objects in the array.